# How to hide toolbar of activity when tablayout is present in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I have toolbar in activity and TabLayout in fragment and i want to hide toolbar of activity when RecyclerView items scroll up, Like this:

[image]

how to achieve this effect? I don't want to create separate toolbar for each fragment that shows this effect.

Thank you.

I have tried this but this isn't working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
  ...Code of coordinator layout...
>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                 ...Code of Tab layout.../>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: You should use the collapsingToolbarLayout and put you toolbar inside it.
Here's where you can read about it
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Read about the collapsing toolbar section in the above article

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your **AppBarLayout** to below one,

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dip"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: I know this already, but i have toolbar in activity. I want to scroll up toolbar of activity by scrolling up the view pager without making new toolbar in fragment.

Answer (score 0):

First add these two librarys to your project.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Then change the theme defiend in your Manifest to a "noActionbar" theme.

Now you can copy an paste this code to your layout and customize it as you like.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"
    app:elevation="4dp">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:text="Your App title"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="snap|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
```

This should do it

Comment: I know this already, but i have toolbar in activity. I want to scroll up toolbar of activity by scrolling up the view pager without making new toolbar in fragment.

Comment: As far as i know this is not possible.

Comment: This piece of code really saved my day! I was having trouble with collapsing bar layout but this helped me a lot!